# DNG converter doesn't convert, Photoshop CS2 doesn't open DNG

Tags: raw, photoshop, macintosh, dng

I am working on OSX 10.6 (Snow Leopard) with Photoshop CS2.
I want to open RAW files from a Sony-RX100.
The Adobe help page says I need the DNG converter 7.2 to convert RX100 RAW files into DNG. To open DNG files in Photoshop CS2, I need the Plug In 3.7.

Downloaded both, stored the plug-in here (Library/Application Support/Adobe/Plug-Ins/CS2/File Formats), put my old plug-in in the trash before, Photoshop wasn't running) and installed the DNG Converter.

The DNG Converter converts as it should but the .dng files won't be opened by Photoshop. The file type is unknown.

A look at [this site](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=39&platform=Macintosh) suggests for Photoshop CS2 a bundle, DNG Converter and RAW Plug In. So I downloaded that, replaced my old plug-in with it and installed the converter. Now the converter won't convert my RX100 RAW files.

Am I looking at that kind of problem "Get a newer computer if you want to work with Photoshop" or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you've certainly run into "The Photoshop Tax" on new cameras. :)  To get Photoshop/ACR to open a RAW file directly, it must be a new enough version that groks the RAW of the camera model. And since RAW is not a file format or a standard, and changes with each camera model, and Adobe has no time-travel capability, this means a version of ACR that came out after your camera was released and whatever version of Photoshop was current at the time, as Adobe only makes the latest version of ACR compatible with the latest version of Photoshop.  So, for the RX100, to use the RAW files directly, you need at least CS6 and ACR 7.2.

Using DNG is the end run around having to upgrade Photoshop.  But you need a version of the DNG converter that can grok your camera's RAW output.  In the case of the RX100, that means you have to have DNG converter 7.2 or later (ACR and DNG typically share version numbers).  Personally, I'd go for the very latest version that runs on Snow Leopard, which is 8.3.

I'm not sure what plugin you were installing, as a plugin is not required to open a DNG file. I used 50D RAW .CR2 files by using the DNG Converter and opening the resulting DNG files directly in Photoshop CS (1).  And any Adobe Camera RAW (ACR) updates you do to CS2 will be too old to understand the RX100 RAW files.

Comment: Hey. Thats what I did. I downloaded the DNG converter 7.2, converted my RAW files (which worked) but were not able to open them in Photoshop. I downloaded ACR 3.7 and put that Plug In into the Library described. Did not help either...

Comment: The ACR plugin has nothing to do with opening DNGs. And overwriting the DNG converter with an older one than 7.2 is why it stopped successfully converting. How are you opening the DNGs?

Comment: The newest version wont run on `10.6`. Thats why I went for `7.2` of the `converter`. I `right click` on the `.dng` file and then `open with`. For my RAW Files from the Canon EOS 350D I normally would have photoshop listed, but not here. So I have to click `chose` and go to my `programmfolder` and chose photoshop.

Comment: Yes. I've already amended to 8.3, rather than 8.4. 8.3 runs on Snow Leopard. Have you tried File -> Open from CS2?

Comment: Just installed `8.3` and tried `File -> Open` in Photoshop. The `.dng` or `.DNG` file is greyshaded and not clickable.

Comment: What do you have the Camera RAW compatibility set to? It should probably be 2.4 for use with CS2; i.e., a version of ACR that CS2 can use.

Comment: Ah alright. I will check that this afternoon and give it a try. I think it is set to 7.4 or 7.2 or something. Cannot tell out of the top of myu head.

Comment: that worked like a charm. its 2.4. thanks for sticking with me!

Answer (score 0):

The RX100 requires a minimum of camera raw 7.2

http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/camera-raw-plug-supported-cameras.html

Photoshop CS2 supports camera raw versions 3.0-3.7

http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/global/camera-raw-compatible-applications.html

So you don't need a new computer, but you need a much more recent version of Photoshop(CS6 or later).

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for the response. I should have added that sentence as well. "Do I need new Photoshop now?". What a crap. Such an expensive peace of software and then you cannot use it when you get new hardware. They just stop the support... That annoys the shi*t out of me.

Comment: Except, the DNG converter should allow Christoph to end-run around the Photoshop tax. DNG is supposed to be the lingua franca of all Photoshop versions.

Comment: sorry for my language but it really is quite annoying... apple does pretty much the same with 10.6 - hardly any support anymore

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the adobe dng converter (most recent version, currently 9.1). When convert your raw-pictures make sure to select the right DNG format to convert to: On the start screen "select "change preferences". Then set compatibility to "camera RAW 2.4 and later". 
It will produce .dng files that can be opened by Photoshop CS2.